# How to pass an array of rows to PDO to insert them?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to use PDO prepared statements but i find it really time consuming to type. it would be super useful if there is a function to just pass the following associative array:

```
array(
"title"=>$title
"userid"=>$userid
"post"=>$body
)
```

Keeping in mind that the keys in the array always match the rows in the SQL table. recaping everything, this should cut off the effort to type the `:foo` and type them again in the execute function.

I'm specifically talking about the INSERT query.

How to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
function pdo_insert($table, $arr=array())
{
  if (!is_array($arr) || !count($arr)) return false;

  // your pdo connection
  $dbh  = '...';
  $bind = ':'.implode(',:', array_keys($arr));
  $sql  = 'insert into '.$table.'('.implode(',', array_keys($arr)).') '.
          'values ('.$bind.')';
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(array_combine(explode(',',$bind), array_values($arr)));

   if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
   {
      return true;
   }

return false;
}

pdo_insert($table, array('title'=>$title, 'userid'=>$user_id, 'post'=>$body));
```

Answer (score -1):

Slighly improved PDO Insert function that also takes security into consideration by preventing SQL Injection attacks:

```
// Insert an array with key-value pairs into a specified database table (MySQL).
function pdo_insert($dbh,$table,$keyvals) {
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s ( `%s` ) %sVALUES ( :%s );",
        $table,
        implode("`, `", array_keys($keyvals)), 
        PHP_EOL, 
        implode(", :", array_keys($keyvals))
    );
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($keyvals as $field => $value) {
        $stmt->bindValue(":$field", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    return $dbh->lastInsertId();
}

// Convert special characters to HTML safe entities.
function h($str) {
    return trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')));
}
```

Example:

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$keyvals = [                
    'id' => isset($_POST['id']) ? h( $_POST['id'] ) : null, 
    'title' => isset($_POST['title']) ? h( $_POST['title'] ) : null,    
    'description' => isset($_POST['description']) ? h( $_POST['description'] ) : null,
    'created_at' => time(),
    'created_by' => 1,
];
$last_ids[] = pdo_insert($dbh,'products',$keyvals);
```