# How to send multiple checkbox value using Angular post method to PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I don't know to send multiple checkbox value to PHP (Server-side).

> **Code**: https://jsfiddle.net/7uLxhnaj/1/

**HTML**

```
<form name="EnqFrm" ng-app="EnqFrm" ng-controller="EnqController" ng-submit="save()">
<label>Class Days:</label>
<input name="chkweek" ng-model="formData.chkweek.Mo" type="checkbox">Mo
<input name="chkweek" ng-model="formData.chkweek.Tu" type="checkbox">Tu
<input name="chkweek" ng-model="formData.chkweek.We" type="checkbox">We
<input name="chkweek" ng-model="formData.chkweek.Th" type="checkbox">Th
<input name="chkweek" ng-model="formData.chkweek.Fr" type="checkbox">Fr
<input name="chkweek" ng-model="formData.chkweek.Sa" type="checkbox">Sa
<button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default">SUBMIT</button>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
/* ANGULAR JS */
var weeksknm;
var app = angular.module('EnqFrm', []);
app.controller('EnqController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.save = function () {
        var url = "Controller/enq_postadmin.php";
        $http.post(url, $scope.formData).success(function (da) {
            alert(da);
            $scope.formData = "";
        });
    };

});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $data=file_get_contents("php://input");
    $inp=json_decode($data);
    echo $txtWeek=$inp->chkweek;
}
else {
    echo'try agian';
}
?>
```

Comment: you can sent multiple check box by creating check boxes array of element

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/7uLxhnaj/3/)

```
var app = angular.module('EnqFrm', []);

app.controller('EnqController', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.formData = {};

$scope.save = function (da) {
    var url = "Controller/enq_postadmin.php";
    $http.post(url, da).success(function (response) {

         // Your action after getting response from server

    });     
    console.log(da);
};

});
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="EnqFrm" ng-app="EnqFrm" ng-controller="EnqController" ng-submit="save(formData.chkweek)">
```

**Console.log Output**

```
Object {Mo: true, Tu: true, We: true}
```

Pass this and get the key across.

Other way around is you need to use ng-true-value

```
 <input name="chkweek" ng-true-value="Monday" ng-model="formData.chkweek.mo" type="checkbox">Mo
```

And your output will be

```
Object {mo: "Monday"}
```

Comment: Happy to help. If you find my answer useful, please check right answer so it will be useful for future readers.

Comment: hi  Alaksandar Jesus Gene
i just want to save 
Object {We: "Wednesday", Th: "Thursday", Mo: "Monday"}
array value to page and parameter for insert query

Comment: Hi..Sorry for the late reply. I dont understand your question. My assumption is my second suggestion. I have updated the jsFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/7uLxhnaj/4/

Comment: i just want to this value to php page where this value saving in database.

Comment: update $http.post. Please look into it. this will pass the value. success will get the response of the server.

Comment: actually its pass array value of weeks and I don't know how to save array value to server using php

Answer (score 0):

Tested working code on my local server. You could later use the $selectedweek to store it in your database.

**PHP**

```
<?php
/*Receive Files*/
$data=file_get_contents("php://input");
$inp=json_decode($data);
/*Convert Object to array*/
foreach($inp as $weekcode => $weekname){
$selectedweek[$weekcode] = $weekname; 
};
/*Pass the selected week array back to angularjs for confirmation*/
print_r($selectedweek);
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="EnqFrm" ng-app="EnqFrm" ng-controller="EnqController" ng-submit="save(formData.chkweek)">
        <label>Class Days:</label>
        <input name="chkweek"  type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'Monday'"  ng-model="formData.chkweek.Mo">Mo
        <input name="chkweek"  type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'Tuesday'" ng-model="formData.chkweek.Tu">Tu
        <input name="chkweek" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'Wednesday'" ng-model="formData.chkweek.We">We
        <input name="chkweek" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'Thursday'" ng-model="formData.chkweek.Th">Th
        <input name="chkweek" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'Friday'" ng-model="formData.chkweek.Fr"> Fr
        <input name="chkweek" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'Saturday'" ng-model="formData.chkweek.Sa">Sa
        <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var app = angular.module('EnqFrm', []);

        app.controller('EnqController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.formData = {};

        $scope.save = function (da) {
        var url = "Controller/enq_postadmin.php";
        $http.post(url, da).success(function (response) {
        console.log(response); // outputs your response from the server
        });     
        console.log(da); // outputs your selection passed from html to controller
        };

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: but how to add to array value to  PDO statement

Comment: public function InsertEnqueryByAdmin($txtWeek) {
        try {
            $this->sql = "INSERT INTO enquirybyadmin("           ClassWeek) "
                    . "VALUES(?)";
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($this->sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $txtWeek, PDO::PARAM_STR);                  
            $stmt->execute();
            return "Form Successfully Submited!";
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587988/how-to-pass-an-array-of-rows-to-pdo-to-insert-them